# How to use extern integer in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, extern

FYI: This is not a complete program but pretty much looks like what mine does.
From what I understand,

I have a header file:

header.cpp

```
extern int global_x;
```

mainWindow.cpp

```
#include "header.cpp" 

int global_x=1;
```

a.cpp

```
#include "header.cpp"

int global_x;
cout << global_x;
```

But my global_x is 0...Why????? If I take out the global_x then it won't compile.
Can someone give an example of a simple program in QT that addresses this issue? I've looked at alot of stuff online, but mostly C uses extern and C++ not as much. thanks.

Comment: You should get linker error about duplicate symbols, since you have `global_x` defined twice. So there's critical difference to your real program, it seems.

Comment: Full working example please! `extern int global_x;` from header.cpp is global. If the `int global_x` is just before the `cout`, it would be local, and hence override the global reference (C++ symbol resolution and scoping rules). If `int global_x` is just next to the #include, you'd get linker errors. And finally `#include cpp` ??? Please look up some c++ coding examples and brush up on basics.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, when you compile your program the include files are slurped in like thus:

**a.cpp**

```
extern int global_x;

int global_x;
cout << global_x;
```

As you can see, when you attempt to compile a.cpp, global_x is never initialized to 1.  Instead it is default initialized to 0 (because it's a global).  That's why you see it as 0.

Comment: Global and static data is initialized to 0 by default, not UB.

Comment: How would I make it so that global_x will be the same value in two different files? Say for instance I want both functions in two different files to first print out their values first and then set a different value. I want the two functions to understand that the extern int is being changed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a linking problem, you do not include `mainWindow.o` when you link the program from `app.cpp`. So, linker complains about missing `global_x`. If you are using Qt (tagged), and manage to do that, you are probably doing it wrong.

Then you add *another* `global_x` to `app.cpp`, and leave it with default value zero (global and static variables have that if you don't initialize them explicitly).

So, to summarize, it seems `mainWindow` is not part of your application, as far as your build system is concerned. Fix that.